# Finding the correct baseaddress

Tags: c#, memory, base-address

I realized that my version of getting the correct `baseaddress` was wrong

```
Process[] iexp = Process.GetProcessesByName("Solitaire");
if (iexp.Length == 0) {
    //EXIT
}
Process internet = iexp[0];
uint baseAddress = (uint)internet.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt64();
```

but the `baseaddress` is wrong

I also looked in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.baseaddress.aspx) but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.baseaddress.aspx) code is very strange and gives me an infinite loop.

I hope you can help me because I can't find any example.

EDIT :

```
 ReadProcessMemory(readHandle, ((IntPtr)(((baseAddress) + 0x14) + 0x50)), bytes, (UIntPtr)4, ref rw);
```

Here i made an image of my desktop.
Im realy confused, maybe someone knows where i made a mistake.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/50lva.jpg

[image]

Comment: How do you know this is returning the wrong Base Address? That code you linked seems reasonable to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want what I think you want, I can only think of a few ways to do it, none of them are .NET built-in though...

1. Use P/Invoke to return the base address of the startup executable.

   ```
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
   ```
2. Returns the base address of the executable containing MyClass

   ```
   Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(typeof(MyClass).Module)
   ```
3. Return a handle to the current module using:

   ```
   Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(this.GetType().Module)
   ```